# Unit testing MassTransit consumers that make utilize asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, restsharp, masstransit

We are using MassTransit asynchronous messaging (on top of RabbitMQ) for our microservice architecture.

We ran into issues testing consumers that in turn make asynchronous calls.

The example below shows a simple MassTransit consumer that uses RestSharp to make an outbound call and utilized the **ExecuteAsync** asynchronous method.

```
public class VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer : Consumes<VerifyPhoneNumber>.Context
{
    IRestClient _restClient;
    RestRequest _request;
    PhoneNumber _phoneNumber;
    PhoneNumberVerificationResponse _responseData;

    public VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer(IRestClient client)
    {
        _restClient = client;
    }

    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<VerifyPhoneNumber> context)
    {
        try
        {
            //we can do some standard message verification/validation here 

            _restClient.ExecuteAsync<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>(_request, (response) =>
            {
                //here we might do some standard response verification

                _responseData = response.Data;

                _phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber()
                {
                    Number = _responseData.PhoneNumber
                };

                context.Respond(new VerifyPhoneNumberSucceeded(context.Message)
                {
                    PhoneNumber = _phoneNumber
                });
            });
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            context.Respond(new VerifyPhoneNumberFailed(context.Message)
            {
                PhoneNumber = context.Message.PhoneNumber,
                Message = exception.Message
            });
        }
    }
}
```

A sample unit test for this might look like the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public class VerifyPhoneNumberConsumerTests
{
    private VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer _consumer;
    private PhoneNumber _phoneNumber;
    private RestResponse _response;
    private VerifyPhoneNumber _command;

    private AutoResetEvent _continuationEvent;
    private const int CONTINUE_WAIT_TIME = 1000;

    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _continuationEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _mockRestClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();
        _consumer = new VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer(_mockRestClient.Object);
        _response = new RestResponse();
        _response.Content = "Response Test Content";
        _phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Number = "123456789"
        };
        _command = new VerifyPhoneNumber(_phoneNumber);
    }

    [Test]
    public  void VerifyPhoneNumber_Succeeded()
    {
        var test = TestFactory.ForConsumer<VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer>().New(x =>
        {
            x.ConstructUsing(() => _consumer);
            x.Send(_command, (scenario, context) => context.SendResponseTo(scenario.Bus));
        });

        _mockRestClient.Setup(
            c =>
            c.ExecuteAsync(Moq.It.IsAny<IRestRequest>(),
                                                            Moq.It
                                                               .IsAny<Action<IRestResponse<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>, RestRequestAsyncHandle>>()))
                                                               .Callback<IRestRequest, Action<IRestResponse<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>, RestRequestAsyncHandle>>((
                                                                   request, callback) =>
                                                               {
                                                                   var responseMock = new Mock<IRestResponse<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>>();
                                                                   responseMock.Setup(r => r.Data).Returns(GetSuccessfulVericationResponse());
                                                                   callback(responseMock.Object, null);
                                                                   _continuationEvent.Set();
                                                               });


        test.Execute();

        _continuationEvent.WaitOne(CONTINUE_WAIT_TIME);

        Assert.IsTrue(test.Sent.Any<VerifyPhoneNumberSucceeded>());
    }

    private PhoneNumberVerificationResponse GetSuccessfulVericationResponse()
    {
        return new PhoneNumberVerificationResponse
            {
                PhoneNumber = _phoneNumber
            };
    }
}
```

Because of the invocation of the **ExecuteAsync** method in the consumer, this test method would fall through if we did not put something to block it until it was signaled (or timed out). In the sample above, we are using **AutoResetEvent** to signal from the callback to continue and run assertions.

**THIS IS A TERRIBLE METHOD** and we are exhausting all resources to try to find out alternatives. If its not obvious, this can potentially cause false failures and race conditions during testing. Not too mention potentially crippling automated testing times.

What alternatives do we have that are BETTER than what we currently have.

**EDIT** Here is a source that I originally used for how to mock RestSharp asynchronous calls.

[How to test/mock RestSharp ExecuteAsync(...)](http://blog.lytzen.name/2013/01/how-to-mock-restsharpexecuteasync.html)

Comment: You need to have a testing framework that is designed to support asynchronous methods; one that properly test methods that return a `Task`, set up an appropriate message loop, observe failures through the returned `Task`, etc.  If your framework doesn't support it, you'll need to more or less do all of that plumbing yourself.  If it does, research how your testing framework of choice supports it.

Comment: Side note: I don't see any asynchronous code in your test - looks like mock version of `ExecuteAsync` is completely synchronous and I'm not sure why you need all that event dance... It probably would be better to delay callback till after method returns (save callback and manually call it after `Consumer` returns)...

Comment: The code in the Moq callback is ran asynchronously after the `text.Execute()`  The code falls through and the test passes if I don't put the reset event in the callback code. Also, consumers don't return since they are responding on the message bus. What you are viewing as an "event dance" is actually just asynchronous message processing.

Comment: @Servy I agree 100%, and my first instinct was to look into asynchronous support in other testing frameworks. and also what I could do with Tasks without switching frameworks. The hurdle I still see is that even that won't solve the problem because none of the consumers actually return, instead they just use the message bus to respond. It seems like I would have to dirty up the consumer code in order to accomplish this.

Comment: @TheJediCowboy If you're working with asynchronous code using an asynchronous model other than the TPL, you may need to convert those operations to the TPL through wrapper methods, unless there are testing frameworks out there that can support a callback style (or some other style) of testing asynchronous methods.

Comment: NUnit supports async unit tests (2.6.4 does anyway). Testing async is hard enough as it is.

Comment: I was able to utilize find what I feel is a proper way of utilizing TPL and will post a solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, the complexity of doing asynchronous methods is one of the key drivers of MassTransit 3. While it isn't ready yet, it makes asynchronous method invocation from consumers so much better.

What you're testing above, because you are calling ExecuteAsync() on your REST client, and not waiting for the response (using .Result, or .Wait) in the consumer, the HTTP call is continuing after the message consumer has returned. So that might be part of your problem.

In MT3, this consumer would be written as:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<VerifyPhoneNumber> context)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _restClient
            .ExecuteAsync<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>(_request);
        var phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Number = response.PhoneNumber
        };

        await context.RespondAsync(new VerifyPhoneNumberSucceeded(context.Message)
        {
            PhoneNumber = _phoneNumber
        });
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        context.Respond(new VerifyPhoneNumberFailed(context.Message)
        {
            PhoneNumber = context.Message.PhoneNumber,
            Message = exception.Message
        });
    }        
}
```

Comment: I didn't see this until after I posted mine. This is amost exactly what I came up with. Except I will need to go back into what we have extended with MassTransit in order to account for awaiting the `context.RespondAsync(...)`. I am going to use yours as the example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with the following solution which seems far more elegant and proper. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong in assuming this.

I modified the RestSharp execution in my consumer so my consumer looks like the following:

public class VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer : Consumes.Context
{
    IRestClient _restClient;
    RestRequest _request;
    PhoneNumber _phoneNumber;
    PhoneNumberVerificationResponse _responseData;

```
public VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer(IRestClient client)
{
    _restClient = client;
}

public void Consume(IConsumeContext<VerifyPhoneNumber> context)
{
    try
    {
        //we can do some standard message verification/validation here 

        var response = await _restClient.ExecuteGetTaskAsync<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>(_request);

        _responseData = response.Data;

        _phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Number = _responseData.PhoneNumber
        };
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        context.Respond(new VerifyPhoneNumberFailed(context.Message)
        {
            PhoneNumber = context.Message.PhoneNumber,
            Message = exception.Message
        });
    }
}
```

}

This utilizes the TPL async capabilities of RestSharp so that I don't have to do it myself.

Because of this, I am able to change my test code to the following:

```
[Test]
public void VerifyPhoneNumber_Succeeded()
{
    var test = TestFactory.ForConsumer<VerifyPhoneNumberConsumer>().New(x =>
    {
        x.ConstructUsing(() => _consumer);
        x.Send(_command, (scenario, context) => context.SendResponseTo(scenario.Bus));
    });

    var response = (IRestResponse<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>)new RestResponse<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>();
    response.Data = GetSuccessfulVericationResponse();

    var taskResponse = Task.FromResult(response);
    Expect.MethodCall(
        () => _client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync<PhoneNumberVerificationResponse>(Any<IRestRequest>.Value.AsInterface))
          .Returns(taskResponse);

    test.Execute();

    Assert.IsTrue(test.Sent.Any<VerifyPhoneNumberSucceeded>());
}
```